# AngularJS: how to call a controller function (with arguments) inside a directive?

Tags: angularjs

The thing I already know:  call a controller function without arguments inside a directive. The code is as below.

First in the directive definition:

```
scope: {
    actionFunc: "&"
}
```

In the directive template:

```
<button ng-click='actionFunc()'></button>
```

Then in controller's HTML view

```
<my-directive action-func='controllFunction()'>
```

Then in controller

```
$scope.controllFunction= function() { 
    alert("controllFunction is called");
};
```

The code above works well.

However, I want to pass arguments to the actionFunc. The controller should look like this:

```
$scope.controllFunction= function(arg1, arg2) { 
    alert(arg1);
    alert(arg2); 
};
```

How to write the HTML view and directive?

Comment: I'm not following completely.  Is the controllFunction inside the directive's Controller? Or is it inside the controller behind the view that contains the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments in an object from within the controller with their names.

In your example, you should do the following:

HTML View

```
<my-directive action-func='controllFunction(myArg1,myArg2)'>
```

Directive template

```
<button ng-click='actionFunc({myArg1: value1, myArg2: value2})'></button>
```

Replace `value1` and `value2` with the appropriate variable